# Why my Update sql Command don't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, database

i have problems with a sql command in mysql. I have a asp.net applcation and use a mysql database as database. I want to built a class that can insert,update,delete and select the records in the database. I have problems with the update command. In phpmyadmin it works but in my class not :/

Here is my code

```
public void UpdateRecord(string title, string firstname, string lastname, string company,
                               string timefrom, string timeto)
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection();

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                //for testing
                string sql = "UPDATE 'tb_gast' SET FIRSTNAME='test' WHERE ID=270";

                command.CommandText = sql;

                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

this command work in phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE `tb_gast` 
SET 
FIRSTNAME='uu',
LASTNAME='uu',
COMPANY='uu'
WHERE ID=270
```

Comment: I'm not sure (about MySQL) but try to remove the single quotes around the table name, eg. UPDATE tb_gast SET...

Comment: All the "It doesn't work" comments would be resolved an awful lot quicker if you removed that empty `Catch(Exception){}` block and let the errors actually get reported. Then, when you've fixed the problem... Don't add it back. Because, the next time something goes wrong, you'll also want to know what the actual errors are, rather than just having this function silently fail.

Comment: Add a MessageBox in catch block 
(Exception ex) -> ex.Message // print this message and tell us the error

Comment: @Sunny - the problem with that approach is that (for unknown exceptions) you still might not be giving enough information (e.g. you're throwing away inner exceptions and stack traces). It's far better to let the exception escape and cause a big ugly crash (full of rich information) if you don't know what the actual error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quote around the tablename, instead of backticks.
The backtick could be typed using the key combination `ALT+096`

```
UPDATE `tb_gast` SET FIRSTNAME = 'test' WHERE ID=270
```

EDIT: Looking at your question more in deep.
Noticed that you declare a MySqlConnection and initialize it WITHOUT any connection strings.
If this is your real code no wonder that it doesn't work

This is how your code should be

```
        using(connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
        {
            connection.Open();
            using(MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            {
                //for testing
                string sql = "UPDATE `tb_gast` SET FIRSTNAME='test' WHERE ID=270";
                command.CommandText = sql;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

where GetConnectionString() should be some method that returns your connection string from some permanent storage like a configuration file

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from the table name `'tb_gast'`. Instead of :

```
UPDATE 'tb_gast' SET FIRSTNAME='test' WHERE ID=270
```

Try this:

```
UPDATE tb_gast SET FIRSTNAME = 'test' WHERE ID=270
```

Comment: this don' work, too :( ...I don't understand where is the problem the syntax must be right :/

Comment: I don't get a error ...but I see in the database that don't work :/

Answer (score 1):

try this one ...

void UpdateRecord(string title, string firstname, string lastname, string company,
                               string timefrom, string timeto)
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection();

```
        try
        {
           string sql = "UPDATE tb_gast SET FIRSTNAME='test' WHERE ID=270";
           MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
           connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```